# Обработка удержания Button C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

В общем есть элемент Button и его событие Click. Нужно прибавлять к счётчику число, но т.к. это требуется делать много раз, чтобы долго не кликать, хотелось бы выполнять действие (прибавлять к счётчику) при удержании Button до отжатия. Можно ли проверить, всё ещё зажата ли кнопка или добавить событие при удержании элемента Button?

Comment: [RepeatButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.repeatbutton)

Comment: Чтобы проверить зажата ли кнопка, можно обратиться к свойству ``IsPressed``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. в данном случае используется платформа UWP, то мы не можем использовать события MouseDown и MouseUp (там их нет). Разобравшись, я реализовал данную задачу чуть по сложнее:
Воспользуемся 3-мя событиями: Click, GotFocus и PointerExited. Так же необходимо создать флаг

```
     private bool    clicFlag;
```

Сам метод обработки нажатия выглядит так:

```
public async void Function()
        {
            clicFlag = true;
            
            //то, что нужно выполнять при простом нажатии (клике)
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                if (PointsEditor.clicFlag) Thread.Sleep(300);
                while (PointsEditor.clicFlag)
                {
                   await PointsEditor.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                        {
                           //то, что нужно выполнять при зажатии кнопки
                        });
                        Thread.Sleep(50); // можно выбрать другое значение задержки
                }
            });
        }
```

Так же нужен метод, переводящи фокус от кнопки на какой нибудь элемент, например TextBox:

```
    private void ClickHandler(TextBox textBox)
    {
        clicFlag = false;
        textBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```

Далее задаём события для кнопки:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ClickHandler(tBoxA);
    private void button_PointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e) 
                                                                => ClickHandler(tBoxA);

    private void button_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Function();
```

Основную функцию выполняет событие GotFocus, которое запускается при наведения фокуса на кнопку. Событие Click вызывается при отжатии кнопки и в данном случае оно выполняет функцию отвода фокуса, после чего метод основной завершается. При нижатии на кнопку и отводе курсора от неё (выход курсора за границы кнопки) событие клик не вызывается. Для этого необходимо собылие PointerExited.

Вот так же пример кода для нескольких кнопок.

```
  private bool    clicFlag;
  private void ChangeChanalValueClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ClickHandler(tBoxA);
  private void ChangeChanalValuePointerExited(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e) => ClickHandler(tBoxA);

  private void chanal_A_minus_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => control.ScrollFunction('a', -1 * programConfig.StepChangevalue);
  private void chanal_A_plus_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => control.ScrollFunction('a', programConfig.StepChangevalue);
```

Метод control.ScrollFunction(...) создан по подобию описанного выше метода Function(). Для каждой кнопки, для которой требуется задержка, события Click и PointerExited обрабатываются методами ChangeChanalValueClick() и ChangeChanalValuePointerExited().

Answer (score 0):

**вот пример увеличения счетчика пока кнопка зажата**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int count = 0;
        private bool _work;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        // нажали и держим кнопку
        private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _work = true; // флаг при котором поток будет работать 
            Thread t = new Thread(UpdateMethod);// поток
            t.Start();// запускаем поток 

        }
        //отпустили кнопку
        private void button2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _work = false;  // останавливаем поток
        }


        // метод 
        void UpdateMethod()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                while (_work)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {

                        count++;
                        label4.Text = count.ToString();
                    }));
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Есть такие Events как MouseDown и MouseUp - остаеться к ним привентить эйвенты и сделать поток.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127270/c-sharp-how-to-loop-while-mouse-button-is-held-down

Или как в этом примере - таймер...